# Change working directory color in NERDTree

Tags: neovim, highlight, plugin-nerdtree

Is there any ways to change the font color and background of the working directory as seen in Sublime text?

Sublime Text

[image]

Neovim with NERDTree

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From their [issue #858](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/858):

> The colors are not configurable NERDTree settings. [...] Try using a different colorscheme. If you don't like any of the default colorschemes, you can always download others as additional plugins.

So you might not be able to do what you want.

---

*Edit* Actually the directories has the highlighting group `NERDTreeCWD` so you could try to change the value of this group. For example something like this might work (I didn't test it):

```
highlight NERDTreeCWD ctermfg=white
```